# JunctionIdList columns in the Event entity

Tags: api, fields, event

By [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_event.htm) Event entity should have AcceptedEventInviteeIds column in v34 API.

But it isn't exist in the Event Fields (app setup).

Also I doesn't see it by using API with [databasedotcom gem](https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom).

How and where I can see AcceptedEventInviteeIds column?

Thanks!